# ld: 0706-005 Cannot find or open file: /lib/mcrt0.o

Tags: imagemagick, aix

I am try to make install the ImageMagick-6.9.10-86 on the AIX system, but error prompted as below :

```
CCLD     magick/libMagickCore-6.Q16.la
/opt/IBM/xlC/16.1.0/bin/.orig/xlc: 1501-210 (W) command option t contains an incorrect subargument
ld: 0706-005 Cannot find or open file: /lib/mcrt0.o
        ld:open(): A file or directory in the path name does not exist.
make: 1254-004 The error code from the last command is 255.


Stop.
make: 1254-004 The error code from the last command is 2.
```

when I try to use `ls -l /lib/mcrt0.o` and `ls -l /usr/ccs/lib/mcrt0.o` command, result as below :

```
ls: 0653-341 The file /lib/mcrt0.o does not exist.

I only can find crt0.o in the path.
```

Comment: Consider clicking `edit` and adding in the full command you actually ran. I don't use AIX, but the difference between `crt0` and `mcrt0` seems to be profiling, so maybe you need to disable profiling somehow.

Comment: Instead of `make all` try `make V=1 all`, it might print more useful information.

Comment: how to disable profiling in AIX?